# I need help in finding regular expression using regexr

Tags: python-2.7

somebody help me to find regular expression into this URL.
I can't find a correct one .
I use regex but I can't find.
.*[(.*)]]>
like this

Comment: What is your question...

Comment: i need to find regular expression into that url

Comment: Which url? There is no url in your question.

Comment: <media:thumbnail width="976" height="549" url="http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/11376/production/_90181507_playgroundpa.jpg"/>